# Bash: Why echo overwrites previous echo

Tags: arrays, bash

I am practicing Bash by displaying all the elements in an array. So far, I have

```
    PATH="\Directory\Stuff"
    echo $PATH
    Array[0]="dad"
    Array[1]="BAD"
```

If I say

```
    echo ${Array[0]}
```

I will output

```
    dad
```

likewise, I will get the correct result accessing the array with index 1. The problem is that this will not work:

```
    echo "${Array[*]}"
```

Looking from online tutorials like [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/), I should expect it to print

```
    dad BAD
```

but instead I get

```
     BAD
```

Note that there is a space before BAD.

I'm not sure why this is occurring. I'm using Cygwin with windows if that helps.

My question is why am I not outputting "dad Bad"?

Comment: BTW, `printf '%q\n' "${Array[@]}"` would have solved this in a way that made your problem very obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have a stray carriage return (a.k.a. `\r` or `^M`) at the end of your `Array[0]`. A carriage return means "go back to the start of the current line", allowing any subsequent text to overwrite what's already been printed.

So your `echo` command is printing `dad`, then immediately rewinding to the beginning of the line and printing  `BAD`, so all you see is the  `BAD`.

To fix this, you just need to remove the carriage return.

Comment: It does come across as a similar issue with a hidden character - otherwise the syntax is correct.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I am on notepad++ and you can switch the file from a windows format (\r\n) to a linux format (\n) going here: http://superuser.com/questions/479756/eol-in-notepad-and-notepad